# What's the amount of psi a 5 gallon water bottle can hold?

Tags: water, pressure

What's the amount of psi a 5 gallon water bottle can hold?
My 5 gallon is filled with beer and a compressor is used to maintain a pressure. I do not want my bottle explodes!

I use a 5 gallon of water because I don't have a normal 5 gallon keg.

Comment: What do you mean by "compressor"? Normally, a CO2 tank is used to carbonate the beer and provide pressure for dispensing. Is this what you're using, or is it something different?

Comment: I presume this bottle is plastic?  Is this bottle for fermentation or for serving?

Comment: What material is the bottle made of? What kind of seal are you using to keep the pressure in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that these are not designed to take pressure, I'd say the maximum safe pressure is **zero**. Any more than that, and you're taking chances.

If that's a chance you're willing to take, then the best way to know the maximum pressure is to get several of these and pressurize to breaking point. The maximum safe pressure is then half of this breaking pressure.

I'm assuming you want to hold pressure to carbonate. Even if you do successfully carbonate without exploding the bottle, further danger comes if you knock the bottle or drop something in it that causes the CO<sub>2</sub> to quickly come out of solution. Then you may get a quick buildup of pressure in the neck of the bottle, more than the bottle will tolerate.

You're far better off saving up for a keg, or using beer bottles, or plastic soda bottles - all of these are designed to take pressure.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to reply to mdma's answer, but he's wrong: >For example, if the bottle is filled to the neck and 15 psi applied, then there is 15psi >pushing down into the neck. This pressure is then distributed throughout the rest of the >water, so the pressure with most of the bottle is going to be significantly less - by the >ratio of the neck opening area to the bottle surface area - in the order of 100 to 1 >reduction. Fluid pressure doesn't work like that; in a static volume if any point is at a particular pressure the rest of the volume is at that pressure (ignoring gravitationa

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I wasn't thinking clearly - I remembered there was some scaling going on, but incorrectly remembered it as pressure rather than force. I've taken that part out, although it doesn't change the main crux of my answer - don't pressurize a non-pressure capable water bottle! :)

Answer (score 0):

A guy in you tube hit 50psi but the cap kept leaking. I am searching for the answer to the same question. Seems like there are a lot of people here who like to give an answer even through they don't have the slightest clue. Better not to speak and be thought a fool than to...anyway. Just for the record in youtube there are several tested who all hit 150 psi with coke and pepsi and 200psi with mountain dew but that is different. In pipes the larger the diameter the less the max PSI. good luck on your project.